# get mouse coordinate in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, mouse, coordinate

I desperately looking for the method to retrieve the mouse coordinates of the user when a click on my contextMenu or when using a shortcutKey

I would like if possible not to have to use the onmousemove event that requires movement of the user :/

Do you know how?

Thank you in advance for your response

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a simple sample, and only works with:

**files**
-> change "matches": ["file:"] in *manifest.json* to add new capabilities

**context menu selection**
-> change contexts: ["selection"] in *contextMenus.create (bg.js)* to add new capabilities

**secondary mouse button**
-> change *(mousePos.button == 2) in (c.js)* to add new capabilities

You can try also with *mousedown* event

For run and test, create these three files, load the extension in chrome, load any file in chrome (example.txt), select any text and then, (secondary mouse button click) new context menu appears. Just click for get Cursor Position.

***Tested and working: 26 march 2014*** on chrome Versión 33.0.1750.154

Any comments are welcome ;)


**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "menuContext position",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "determine menuContext position",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bg.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["file:///*/*"],
    "js": ["c.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "all_frames": true
  }],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**c.js**

```
'use strict';

// when mouse up, send message to background.js with this position
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (mousePos) {
  if (mousePos.button == 2) {
    var p = {clientX: mousePos.clientX, clientY: mousePos.clientY};
    var msg = {text: 'example', point: p, from: 'mouseup'};
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg, function(response) {});
  }
})
```

**bg.js**

```
'use strict';

//global var for store cursor position
var gPos = null;

//receiving message
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (msg.from == 'mouseup') {
    //storing position
    gPos = msg.point;
  }
})

// onclick callback function.
function OnClick(info, tab, text, mousePos) {
  if (info.menuItemId == idConsole) {
      if (gPos != null) {
          alert('Position X: ' + gPos.clientX + '\nPosition Y: ' + gPos.clientY );
          //console.log('Position X: ' + gPos.clientX + '\nPosition Y: ' + gPos.clientY );
      }
  }
}

//on click sample callback with more params
var idConsole = chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: 'Cursor Position',
  contexts: ["selection"],
  onclick: function(info, tab) {
    OnClick(info, tab, '%s', gPos);
  }
})
```

Please, if possible, add tag [google-chrome-extension] to your question. Greetings

Comment: if test ok, do not forget mark as valid response. if test fail, please comment. Greetings

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget add tag [google-chrome-extension]. Tags are usefull for people finding solutions.